# jQuery check if element has sibling

Tags: jquery, html

I need a tip from you. I've a table with buttons in each row. Sometimes the row can have one button and sometime two. Now I'm trying to set a class which sets a margin-right to the left button (in case there are 2 buttons) to make a little gap between them.

This is my code:

```
if (jQuery('.woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-actions a').next('a').length > 1) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('no-arrow margin-right');
} else {
    jQuery(this).addClass('no-arrow');
}
```

But now I've the problem that the table looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is no gap between the buttons at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Javascript or even jQuery here, this is very easy to solve using CSS only. Use the *adjacent sibling selector* `button + button` that says *target buttons that are directly preceded by another button*:

```css
div {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 0;
}

div button {
  margin: 0;
}

div button + button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">Button A</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <button type="button">Button A</button>
  <button type="button">Button B</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <button type="button">Button A</button>
  <button type="button">Button B</button>
  <button type="button">Button C</button>
</div>
```

As you can see this also works for more than two buttons.

If you add your HTML to your post, I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Lol, props to you Jesus. What a smart solution. Never thought about this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .siblings() https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ to check for siblings if you want.  However, you may end up with a better and cleaner result by using the CSS :last-child selector to set a margin-right to 0 after setting margin-right to 10px (or whatever) for everything else that matches.